# How to tell node.js which javascript code runs on server vs client?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to learn the theory of node.js but can't seem to figure out how node.js knows whether to pre process it on the server or send it to browser for execution.

Comment: node.js does not execute code client-side.  It does not pre-process anything.  node.js is a server-side platform only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `node example.js` runs the code server side.
- `require('./example.js')` within the server-side JavaScript file also runs the code server side.
- [Serving a static file](http://ericsowell.com/blog/2014/6/17/enough-node-for-building-a-simple-website) ending with ".js" to a client will make it a client-side JavaScript.

Comment: ok thanks for the help. I couldnt find that anywhere in documentation.